# What is the role of "one" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammatical-roles

I can't understand what is the role of word "one" in this sentence:

> A hillside in the morning so radiant with light one has the feeling he
>   has been looking at Van Gogh's drawings.

Source: The Guardian

I know that it says the hillside is very radiant such as Van Gogh's drawings. But I don't understand what role word "one" grammatically has and what does it mean in the sentence.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: *One,* an unspecified person, any person in general.  Look it up in a good dictionary. Good Luck.

Comment: By role, I assume you mean function; in which case it's the subject of the subordinate clause _one has the feeling he has been looking at Van Gogh's drawings_. Categorywise, it's a personal pronoun used non-referentially for talking about people generally rather than in reference to a particular individual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an indefinite pronoun used as the subject of the sentence. 
It means 'everyone' or 'somebody'.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

***ONE***

- an individual of a vaguely indicated group
- anyone at all
 // one never knows

Comment: "'everyone' or 'somebody'" -- in fact, *anyone,* for that matter.